# Algorithm to handle data aggregation from multiple error-prone sources

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

I'm aggregating concert listings from several different sources, none of which are both complete and accurate. Some of the data comes from users (such as on last.fm), and may be incorrect. Other data sources are highly accurate, but may not contain every event. I can use attributes such as the event date, and the city/state to try to match listings from disparate sources. I'd like to be reasonably certain that the events are valid. It seems like it would be a good strategy to consume as many different sources as possible to validate listings on error-prone sources.

I'm not sure what the technical term for this is, as I'd like to research it further. Is it data mining? Are there any existing algorithms? I understand a solution will never be completely accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is [Record Linkage](http://www.answers.com/topic/record-linkage) -

> the process of bringing together two or more records relating to the same entity(e.g., person, family, event, community, business, hospital, or geographical area)

[This presentation (PDF)](https://www.soa.org/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=4380) looks like a nice introduction to the field. One algorithm you might use is [Fellegi-Holt](http://www.fcsm.gov/working-papers/wp25a_2.pdf) - a statistical method for editing records.

Comment: link to pdf you gave is no longer valid

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that locates it within statistics - specifically, it uses a Hidden Markov Model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model):

1) Use your matching process to produce a cleaned list of possible events. Consider each event to be marked "true" or "bogus", even though the markings are hidden from you. You might imagine that some source of events produces them, generating them as either "true" or "bogus" according to a probability which is an unknown parameter.

2) Associate unknown parameters with each source of listings. These give the probability that this source will report a true event produced by the source of events, and the probability that it will report a bogus event produced by the source.

3) Notice that if you could see the markings of "true" or "bogus" you could easily work out the probabilities for each source. Unfortunately, of course, you can't see these hidden markings.

4) Let's call these hidden markings "Latent Variables" because then you can use the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_algorithm to hillclimb to promising solutions for this problem, from random starts.

5) You can obviously make the problem more complicated by dividing events up into classes, and giving sources of listing parameters which make them more likely to report some classes of events than others. This might be useful if you have sources that are extremely reliable for some sorts of events.

Comment: Very thorough, but perhaps a bit over my head. Appreciate it though.

Answer (score 1):

One potential search term is "fuzzy logic".

I'd use a float or double to store a probability (0.0 = disproved ... 1.0 = proven) of some event details being correct.  As you encounter sources, adjust the probabilities accordingly.  There's a lot for you to consider though:

- attempting to recognise when multiple sources have copied from each other and reduce their impact
- giving more weight to more recent data or data that explicitly acknowledges the old data (e.g. given a 100% reliable site saying "concert X to be held on 4th August", and a unknown blog alleging "concert X moved from 4th August to 9th", you might keep the probability of there being such a concert at 100% but have a list with both dates and whatever probabilities you think appropriate...)
- beware assuming things are discrete; contradictory information may reflect multiple similar events, dual billing, same-surnamed performers etc. - the more confident you are that the same things are referenced, the more the data can combined to reinforce or negate each other
- you should be able to "backtest" your evolving logic by using data related to a set of concerts where you now have full knowledge of their actual staging or lack thereof; process data posted before various cut-off dates prior to the events to see how the predictions you derive reflect the actual outcomes, tweak and repeat (perhaps automatically)

It may be most practical to start scraping from the sites you have, then consider the logical implications of the types of information you're seeing.  Which aspects of the problem need to be handled using fuzzy logic can then be decided.  An evolutionary approach may mean reworking things, but may end up faster than getting bogged down in a nebulous design phase.

Comment: Thankfully, I only have to detect duplicates and use multiple sources for verification. Normalization of venues will be a big problem, however.

Answer (score 0):

Data mining is about finding information from structured sources like a database, or a post where the fields are separated for you. There's some text mining in here when you have to parse the information out of free text. In either case, you could keep track of how many data sources agree on a show as a confidence measure. Either display the confidence measure or use it to decide if your data is good enough. There's lots to play with. Having a list of legitimate cities, venues and acts can help you decide if a string represents a legitimate  entity. Your lists might even be in a database that lets you compare city and venue for consistency.